# Java application appears in other unity workspace

Tags: java, workspaces

So to clarify a few facts first:

- with "unity workspace" I mean the workspaces in ubuntu which I switch to using ctrl+alt+arrows. I do not mean the eclipse workspaces
- I use openjdk java 7
- I have myUnity and Compizconfig Settingsmanager installed, and I use 9 (3x3) workspaces.

The issue:

I use eclipse to create a program for school. Each time I launch the program from eclipse, or just from command line with an exported jar, the application opens in the workspace right to the one I'm working in. If I use the most right workspace, it'll just pop up in the first one. Anyone knows why this happens and how to fix it?

Regards,
Brent

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, foud a way around it.
Add the `WindowOpened()` event to your `JFrame` and type:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
    this.setLocation(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same, even if I use oracle JDK instead of openJDK.
I've solved the problem by the previous way : this.setlocation(0,0)

I've also tested this :

setLocation(0,2000) -> this display the window to the right workspace (my screen resolution is 1600*1200)

setLocation(1500,0) -> window will appear in the bottom workspace ...

It seems that UNITY considers workspaces as a unique big screen. If I have 4 workspaces with a resolution of 1600*2000, i could consider that I have a unique screen of a resolution of (1600*4)*(1200*4). Using setLocation(x,y) I may be able to position my window in any workspace.

Regards